# Autoloading em Classes PHP

Tags: php

O que seria o **Autoloading de Classes em PHP?**

Vejo pessoas usando `__autoload` e `spl_autoload_register` existe diferença?

Que associação existe entre o **autoloader** do **composer** e o **autoloading** convencional?
São estas duas funções que estão a ser usadas debaixo dos panos no **autoloader** do **composer**?

Comment: **1)** Autoloading de Classes é a verificação, carregamento de um determinado arquivo em seu sistema. É como se você tivesse utilizando `require` ou `include` de forma automática.  Evitando todo aquele código com inúmeros `require`. O *autoloading* também evita que você carregue arquivos sem necessidade. Isso porque quando você for, de fato, utilizá-los, a função que você definir em `spl_autoload_register` já fará isso na hora certa, sem prejuízo para o sistema.

Comment: **2)** Sim, existem diferenças entre ambas. A principal delas é que `spl_autoload_register` permite multiplas funções de *autoload*, já `__autoload` é limitado a uma. Uma outra diferença bem importante é que `__autoload` está deprecado no PHP 7.2+

**4)** É a função `spl_autoload_register` que o *Composer* utiliza para carregamento de classes.